# Drude vs Sommerfeld theory - resource?

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, electrical-resistance

I am looking for a book/any other resource which clearly lays out all the predictions of Drude theory and Sommerfeld theory and the extent to which each prediction holds. I am able to find some information on this topic in e.g. Singleton (2001) chapter 1. But this does not give the comprehensive overview that I am looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ashcroft and Mermin' Solid State Physics devotes the first two chapters to Drude and Sommerfeld, and then the third chapter is on the failings of the models. And it is a classic solid state physics book.

Comment: @JonCuster Hi thanks for this, from what I can tell they only really go into the details of the failures of the Sommerfeld model - I am kind of looking for a source that does them both together. (ideally in the format of e.g. a table but I think this would be hard to find).

Comment: Well, the Sommerfeld model was in response to the failings of the Drude model. I think you will be hard pressed to find a better short summary than Chapter 3...